# Making a specific URL not show up in Chrome's address suggestions? (Youtube home)

Tags: google-chrome

When I go to Youtube, I want to go to `https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions` instead of `https://www.youtube.com`. Even if I delete `https://www.youtube.com` from the suggestions, it still comes back after a while. Even though I select `https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions` every time, `https://www.youtube.com` still becomes the #1 suggestion.

Is it possible to permanently forbid Chrome from suggesting `https://www.youtube.com`? When I start typing `youtube`, I still want it to suggest `https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions`.

Answer (score 0):

The autosuggested URLs in the browser address bar are based on websites that you have visited. I believe the more regularly you visit the website the higher precedence it gets.

If you want to see https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions instead of https://www.youtube.com you would have to make sure that https://www.youtube.com is not existing in your browser history.

One way to do this is to clear your browser history and only visit https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions ; then https://www.youtube.com will not be suggested.

Comment: I go to the homepage once in a while, but I go to the subscriptions page more. It looks like Chrome always prioritizes homepages over other pages